# How is decoded audio data stored in ffmpeg AVFrame?

Tags: c, audio, ffmpeg, decoding

I'm looking for clarification on how ffmpeg stores decoded audio data in frames before I start writing code to do audio mixing. `AVFrame` has `int format` and `uint8_t* data[]` members. If my understanding is correct, then the bytes in `data` should be cast to the proper type for `format` before working with it. So to do a simple 2x level boost if `format == AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16`, I would:

```
int16_t* audio_samples = frame->data[0];
int num_samples = frame->nb_samples * frame->channels;
for (int i = 0; i < num_samples; ++i) {
  audio_samples[i] = audio_samples[i] * 2;
}
```

Is this the correct way of going about things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your understanding of audio seems correct.
For packed formats like `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16` you only need `AVFrame::data[0]` as for planar formats like `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP` you'll need other indexes too.

`AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16` is signed 16bit format, which means every single sample is between -32768, and +32767.

So, in your case, you already have what you need:
`int16_t *audio_samples = frame->data[0]`: this is your current audio data buffer.
`num_samples = frame->nb_samples * frame->channels`: `num_samples` here is the size of this buffer (unit s16).

I can't say your code in the loop is wrong, this might actually would work but the problem is there is a potential risk of overflow, you should implement saturation to prevent it.