# Is raw audio in AVFrame->data the same as LPCM?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec, libavformat

In the ffmpeg documentation for an `AVFrame` it says

> This structure describes decoded (raw) audio or video data.

In the case of audio data, what format are the samples within an `AVFrame` in? Do they basically look like raw LPCM samples? If you decode audio data into an `AVFrame` (i.e. via `avcodec_send_packet() ... avcodec_receive_frame()`) does the audio data of the packet look the same, regardless of what encoding it was originally in in the packet (assuming the same sample rate, sample format, etc)?

Based on the question [How is decoded audio data stored in ffmpeg AVFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889455/how-is-decoded-audio-data-stored-in-ffmpeg-avframe) it seems like this is the case, but I want to know if this is the same as LPCM, regardless of what encoding the audio data was in before?

Bonus question: If it is the same as LPCM, why would you use a PCM encoder (e.g. ""pcm_f32le") to encode the frame data to `AVPacket`s? Does the internal data look the same? Is it just in order to use functions that take `AVPacket`s like `av_interleaved_write_frame()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, it can be whatever the audio decoder outputs e.g. DSD, but ffmpeg raw audio is expected to be LPCM by other components e.g. filters, encoders.

You would use a PCM encoder because the output PCM format or endianess may be different.